# How to create an animation of particles in Maple?

Tags: numerical-methods, graphing-functions, 3d, maple

Using *Maple*, I numerically solved some differential equations describing a set of interacting particles.  I can plot the trajectories in 3D space, and the output is pretty.  But I also need to show the motion of all the particles (animation).  How can I do this with *Maple* ?  I'm not an experienced user of *Maple* and the help system doesn't help me much with this.

For exemple, here's the *Maple* code to show the trajectories in 3D (of course, that code won't compile on your system since it's just a small part of the whole code) :

```
plots[odeplot](Trajectory,
    [
        [xA0(t), yA0(t), zA0(t)],
        [xA1(t), yA1(t), zA1(t)],
        [xA2(t), yA2(t), zA2(t)],
        [xB0(t), yB0(t), zB0(t)],
        [xB1(t), yB1(t), zB1(t)],
        [xB2(t), yB2(t), zB2(t)]
    ],
    T1..T2,
    numpoints = 10000, axes = boxed, scaling = constrained,
    thickness = [2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1],
    color = ["Magenta", "Green", "Blue", "Brown", "Gray", "Cyan"],
    labels = ["X", "Y", "Z"]);
```

The animation should show the 6 particles as small dots moving in time.  The particles should use the same colors as defined in the code above.

Any suggestion on how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

I did something like you wish years ago. I hope you can get what you want:

```
[> with(plots);
  f1 := proc (rho, phi, theta) options operator, arrow; rho*cos(theta)*sin(phi) end proc;
  f2 := proc (rho, phi, theta) options operator, arrow; rho*sin(theta)*sin(phi) end proc;
  f3 := proc (rho, phi, theta) options operator, arrow; rho*cos(phi) end proc;
  s := spacecurve([cos(2*t), sin(2*t), t], t = 0 .. 10, axes = normal, color = red, thickness = 2, numpoints = 200);
  w := animate3d([cos(2*t)+f1(0.3e-1, phi, theta), sin(2*t)+f2(0.3e-1, phi, theta), t+f3(0.3e-1, phi, theta)], phi = -4 .. 4, theta = -4 .. 4, t = 0 .. 10, frames = 50);
  display(s, w);
```

[image]

Comment: I'm unable to get the animation (I'm using Maple 13).  Why the **[>** ?  And why the **f1**, **f2** and **f3** ?  Isn't there a "dot" or ball primitive in *Maple* ?

Comment: the command **animate3d** has been deprecated. We should use the superseding command **plots[animate]** instead, but I'm still unable to get an animation.

Comment: It is interesting that I am unable to see what I enclosed above!! :-)) But you can remove `[>` and I added it because on making the codes real as they appear in a Maple sheet.